# Adjust Data insert to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Adjust(App Tracking tool) provide raw data with csv.gz extension. This data in my bucket. I want to send data to bigquery automatically, and delete historical data csv.gz files.  How to success case? I don't have any idea about cloud function.

Answer (score 3):

You can able to perform this by using below steps:

1. Create a Cloud Storage bucket
2. Create a Cloud Function using `Trigger Type` as "Cloud Storage" and link the Cloud Storage bucket name created in Step[1]
3. In the Cloud Function code, read the Cloud Storage blob using `bigquery.Client()`
4. Once the data is successfully load into BigQuery, you can archive/backup the file using `storage.Client()` and "**copy_blob**" method